# Is there a word for the towel on a waiter's arm?

Tags: vocabulary

"Napkin" or "towel" seem so...ordinary. Is there a better word for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Napkin](http://www.napkinfoldingguide.com/napkins/) is the correct term:

> - what about that waiter who carries a napkin draped over one arm? In part, it’s practicality. It’s readily available to mop up any accidental spills or other messes at your table. But the practice dates back a couple of hundred years in France; that was how waiters carried the napkins they would distribute to diners. Napkins have been in use for thousands of years.

If you want a less common alternative you can use [serviette:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serviette)

> - (chiefly British)
>     :  a table napkin

Comment: The labor organization for waiters is the serviette union.   (I couldn't resist that one.)

Answer (score 4):

When I worked as a waiter in Scotland in the 1970s we called it a dadel. Not sure of the spelling as I never saw it written down, so it may have been dadle.

Thanks to the later contributor who provided the correct spelling as daidle, but who also said that the English translation for the word is actually an apron.

Presumably due to having the incorrect spelling of the word, I could not find it on any of the Scots dictionaries, but I did find the translation for the correct spelling in the DSL, Dictionaries of the Scots Language. This gives 4 translations for the word as a noun, one of which is a napkin, which would seem to conform with us calling the towel we carried over our arm as a daidle. Which is what we did call it.

As other contributors noted, it was very useful for light cleaning and handling hot items. I did also put out a small fire with it in a restaurant after an accident with a flaming Sambuca.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, that was the apron. OED **daidle** (n.) - *Chiefly Scottish.* -- **A pinafore.**...a1800 Jenny [shall have] the sark of God For—petticoat, dishclout, and daidle. *Jacobite Relics (1819) vol. I. 7*

Comment: @Alan You appear to have created two accounts. If this is the case, then they can be merged so that the rep attached to your unregistered account is accrued to your registered account. See the [help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

In the F&B industry it is termed as "Waiter's cloth".

Comment: This would be improved with a source for these terms ('F&B industry', 'waiter's cloth').

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the French word for that napkin. In French it's called *liteau*. The plural should be *liteaux*.

Comment: Thanks, Ernesto, but ELU is English-specific.